# Why is recursion not the same as dynamic programming in some cases?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am working on dynamic programming and I came across a problem to find unique paths to reach a point 'b' from point 'a' in a m x n grid. You can only move right or down. My question is why is the following recursive approach much slower than the dynamic one described later?

---

Recursion:

```
def upaths(m,n):
    count = [0]
    upathsR(m,n, count)
    return count[0]

def upathsR(m,n,c):
    # Increase count when you reach a unique path
    # When you reach 1 there is only one way to get to an end (optimization)
    if m==1 or n==1:
        c[0]+=1
        return

    if m > 1:
        upathsR(m-1,n,c)
    if n > 1:
        upathsR(m,n-1,c)
```

Dynamic:

```
def upaths(m, n):
    count = [[1 for x in range(n)] for x in range(m)]
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            count[i][j] = count[i][j-1] + count[i-1][j]
    return count[-1][-1]
```

Usually recursion has repetitive calls that can be memoized but in this case I see unique calls, Even so Recursion is much slower. Can someone explain why..

---

Following suggestions from the answers, it worked faster. And the calls aren't unique.

New Recursive Approach:
def upaths(m,n):
  d = dict()
  return upathsR(m,n,d)

```
def upathsR(m,n,d):
    if (m,n) in d:
        return d[(m,n)]

  if m==1 or n==1:
      return 1

  d[(m,n)] = upathsR(m-1,n,d)+upathsR(m,n-1,d) 
  return d[(m,n)]
```

Comment: The calls are not always unique. Try to draw the tree of function calls upto depth 3 or 4, then you'll see it.

Comment: Why are you using an array that's always the same length? It looks like you're doing it just to avoid returning a value from the function.

Comment: @Barmar python does not allow to change an immutable variable in another function, so wrapping it in a list.

Comment: @0605002 So if I save those cases in a dictionary? Or memoize it somehow it will be as fast as the dynamic approach?

Comment: You should move the "fixed" code into an answer, since there doesn't seem to be much of a question left right now. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on Stack Overflow, just make sure you do write it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @learner That's exactly the idea of dynamic programming. Whenever you encounter a repeated function call, use the previously memoized answer instead of evaluating it again.

Comment: @learner My point was that you don't need to mutate anything, return it as a value instead.